# Decision Theory: Why is it called a "least favorable prior"?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, definition, decision-theory

I'm currently reading the chapter on Statistical Decision Theory in Larry Wasserman's "All of Statistics". Reading the section 13.4 about *Minimax Rules* he introduces the so called *Least favorable prior*.

> Theorem $13.11$ Let $\widehat{\theta}^{\pi}$ be the Bayes rule for some prior $\pi$ :
> $$
> r\left(\pi, \widehat{\theta}^{\pi}\right)=\inf _{\widehat{\theta}} r(\pi, \widehat{\theta})
> $$
> Suppose that
> $$
> R\left(\theta, \widehat{\theta}^{\pi}\right) \leq r\left(\pi, \widehat{\theta}^{\pi}\right) \text { for all } \theta
> $$
> Then $\widehat{\theta}^{\pi}$ is minimax and $\pi$ is called a **least favorable prior**.

Why is $\pi$ called the "least favorable" prior ? Is it because the minimax approach is more pessimistic that the bayes one and this prior therefore is the most "pessimistic" one out of all the possible priors ?

Comment: I previously struggled with this part also, and from a self-study perspective, this is one of the terser parts of the book if you've never encountered minimax theory before. Have you considered working through and understanding the proof by contradiction he has supplied, as a starting point?

Comment: Yes I did, and I actually understood how it works. I'm still not certain whether I understand why this proof is important though, but today I'm going to look at the examples that follow it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the name originates but here is my opinion on it.

The Bayes risk is some average of the risk function of the Bayes estimator, weighted by the prior. The least favorable prior only places weight on the part of the risk function that achieves the supremum. One example of such could be a Dirac delta at the $\arg \sup_{\theta} \text{R} (\theta, \hat{\theta})$.

However, there is a slight problem with this example. Namely, we cannot choose the least favorable prior after fixing a risk function, since the risk function is determined by the prior. So in reality, the prior comes first and the risk function of the Bayes estimator can be determined. If then we realize the prior happens to place all the weights on the supremum of the risk, we have found the least favorable prior.